# javascript - Make a line from one point that follows cursor

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation

I would like to make 1px wide line where its point A will be in a given div, and point B will be in user's cursor, so when I move the mouse, the Line is moving also. Please give me some ideas, libraries, etc.

Comment: See if this can help you,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35174822/4739933

Answer (score 1):

As @Amit Mankotia said, use the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174326/canvas-draw-line-by-following-mouse-cursor/35174822#35174822) to a very similar stack overflow question. You have two options:

- Use the [similar question's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174326/canvas-draw-line-by-following-mouse-cursor/35174822#35174822)'s code using jQuery and the event object
- Use this [link's](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/processingjs-inside-webpages-template/5157014494511104) code from Khan Academy using Processing JS

If you chose the second option,

1. Copy and paste the code.
2. Take out the smiley face code
3. Use the following code

   size(400, 400);
   frameRate(30);
   // ProgramCodeGoesHere
   var draw = function() {
   background(255, 125, 60)
   strokeWeight(1);
   stroke(0, 0, 0);
   line(mouseX, mouseY, 40, 50)
   }

Now change `40, 50` to whatever numbers you want for the x (40) and y (50).